# How to attach domain to VPS server

Tags: dns, webserver, self-hosting

I just bought a domain at godaddy whatever. I do have a VPS server hosted by iniz.

Now when i try to link the domain which i just bought with my VPS server in my 'iniz client area' they want me to pay 17USD per year to host the domain?

Why would i have to pay for putting domain which i own and payed for on the server i own and pay for monthly ?. Is there a DIY way of linking website with server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into your godaddy settings and point it at the iniz server. Not in the iniz settings.

Comment: Yes indeed you are right :) Thank you for pointing this to me